importing WRL files with bad sliced surfaces fix
total beginner here. I need to put artwork (textures) on flat surface 3D units for my work and need to import WRL files that have been exported from the CAD team, when I import the files in edit mode they are all sliced up instead of a flat surface like this: 
Is there a way to fix this quickly without having to pick out each slice to UV map it?
Thanks

It looks like you’ve got Z fighting problems with the shelf model in the background, which indicates doubled mesh. I can’t tell from your description if you just need to do Limited Dissolve, or Merge Vertices By Distance and learn about how UV mapping works. If you can, share your blend file with blend-exchange.com

Instructions for sharing your Blender project file.
